# hc-05 display incoming data in TextVieww

Tags: java, android, mobile, bluetooth

I've searched all the topics on stack and Im still stuck with it.

What I m try to do is first display incoming data via bluetooth from microcontroler to TextView strDlugosc and strLenght.

Next step after that will be seperate all the data into Temperature and Voltage TextViews.

I dont know whats going on with it that it dont displaying it...

Please help me

```
//buttony
Button b_Onled1, b_Onled2, b_Offled1, b_Offled2;
TextView temp_1, temp_2, nap_1, nap_2, strLenght, strDlugosc;
String address = null;


private ProgressDialog progress;
BluetoothAdapter Bta = null;
BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private boolean isBtConnected = false;
final int handlerState = 0;
protected static final int SUCCESS_CONNECT = 0;
protected static final int MESSAGE_READ = 1;

//SPP UUID
static final UUID mojeUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");


@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kontrola__led);

    Intent newint = getIntent();
    address = newint.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_ADDRESS);


    //wywolanie
    b_Onled1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_Onled1);
    b_Onled2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_Onled2);
    b_Offled1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_Offled1);
    b_Offled2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_Offled2);
    temp_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temp_1);
    temp_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temp_2);
    nap_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nap_1);
    nap_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nap_2);
    strLenght = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.strLenght);
    strDlugosc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.strDlugosc);


    //wywolaj klase by polaczyc
    new PolaczBT().execute();


    //KOMENDY ONCLICK
    b_Onled1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            wlaczLED1();
        }
    });

    b_Onled2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            wlaczLED2();
        }
    });

    b_Offled1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            wylaczLED1();
        }
    });

    b_Offled2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            wylaczLED2();
        }
    });


}

Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {

            case MESSAGE_READ:

                ConnectThread connectthread = new ConnectThread(btSocket);
                connectthread.start();

                final byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                final String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);

                strLenght.setText(readMessage);
                break;
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};


private void Disconnect() {
    if (btSocket != null) //jezeli socket jest zajety
    {
        try {
            btSocket.close(); //przerwij polaczenie
        } catch (IOException e) {
            msg("ERROR");
        }
    }
    finish(); // powraca do pierwszego layuoutu
}

private void wylaczLED1() {
    if (btSocket != null) {
        try {
            btSocket.getOutputStream().write("01D0$".toString().getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            msg("ERROR");
        }
    }
}

private void wylaczLED2() {
    if (btSocket != null) {
        try {
            btSocket.getOutputStream().write("02D0$".toString().getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            msg("ERROR");
        }
    }
}

private void wlaczLED1() {
    if (btSocket != null) {
        try {
            btSocket.getOutputStream().write("01D1$".toString().getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            msg("ERROR");
        }
    }
}

private void wlaczLED2() {
    if (btSocket != null) {
        try {
            btSocket.getOutputStream().write("02D1$".toString().getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            msg("ERROR");
        }
    }
}


//************************************************************************
//metoda do przywolywania TOAST*******************************************
//************************************************************************
private void msg(String s) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


//*************************************************************************
//POLACZENIE BLUETOOTH*****************************************************
//*************************************************************************
private class PolaczBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private boolean ConnectSuccess = true;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(Kontrola_Led.this, "Laczenie...", "Prosze czekaj!");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... devices) {
        try {
            if (btSocket == null || !isBtConnected) {
                Bta = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                BluetoothDevice dyspozycyjnosc = Bta.getRemoteDevice(address);
                btSocket = dyspozycyjnosc.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mojeUUID);
                BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
                btSocket.connect();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ConnectSuccess = false;
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (!ConnectSuccess) {
            msg("Blad polaczenia. Czy SPP BLUETOOTH dziala? Ponow probe. ");
            finish();
        } else {
            msg("Connected.");
            isBtConnected = true;
        }
        progress.dismiss();
    }
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    final InputStream mmInStream;
    final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {

        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
        int bytes;

        while (true) {
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                String strIncom = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                sb.append(strIncom);
                int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");
                if (endOfLineIndex > 0){
                    String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);
                    strDlugosc.setText(sbprint);
                }

                mHandler.obtainMessage(Kontrola_Led.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();



            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: did you check if `handleMessage` is called ta all?

Comment: it's called only in connectthread so I think for now its enough

Comment: Insert a log Log.e("anything",readMessage); before strLenght.setText(readMessage); First we must know if it's reaching your code or not and that readMessage is not null or empty string.

Comment: Thank you I had problems with sockets know Im on a way to solve it .